# How to map components and ensure the component has the same attribute individually

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have a map function that render a serial of image, and I realized that they share the same `hover` state, which means they will perform the same action when hovered. Is there are any standard practice to map duplicate components while assigning them unique/individual properies?

```
      {itemData.map((item) => (
        <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
          <img
            src={item.img}
            alt={item.title}
            loading="lazy"
            onMouseOver={() => {setHover(true)}}
            onMouseOut={() => {setHover(false)}}
            style={{ transform: hover ? 'scale(1.5, 1.5)' : null }}
          />
          <ImageListItemBar
            title={item.title}
            subtitle={item.author}
            actionIcon={
              <IconButton
                sx={{ color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)' }}
                aria-label={`info about ${item.title}`}
              >
                <InfoIcon />
              </IconButton>
            }
          />
```

Comment: Extract a sub component? Have a number or array state instead of boolean, to match the cardinality of what you're using it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a component, which create a unique state for each element, i wrote an easy to understand example.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const items = [
  {
    title: 'Card1',
    price: 100
  },
  {
    title: 'Card2',
    price: 50
  },
  {
    title: 'Card3',
    price: 200
  },
]

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {
        items.map(element => {
          return(
            <Card {...element}/>
          )
        })
      }
    </>
  )
}

function Card({title, price, key}) {
  const [isHovered, setHover] = useState(false) 
  
  return (
    <>
    <div
    key={key}
    onMouseOver={() => {setHover(true)}}
    onMouseOut={() => {setHover(false)}}
    >
      <div>
        {title}
      </div>
      <h3>
        {
          isHovered && price
        }
      </h3>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I made the card price to show if hovered so you can see it works on each individual component.

[Code sandbox if you want to check it out.](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-archimedes-i9mheu?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I have tried both method, yours one is a little bit better I think, clearer code, and less buggy. Thanks for your ans

Answer (score 1):

To provide unique properties, you need to have something that uniquely identifies your image component and use it to manage your state. In your case, your state `hover` should be an `array` or an `object`, not a `boolean`. Since you are using `item.img` as a key, I assume it is unique and hence it can help in your state management like this:

```
const [hover, setHover] = useState({});
{itemData.map((item) => (
        <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
          <img
            src={item.img}
            alt={item.title}
            loading="lazy"
            onMouseOver={() => setHover({...hover, [item.img]: true})}
            onMouseOut={() => setHover({...hover, [item.img]: false})}
            style={{ transform: hover ? 'scale(1.5, 1.5)' : null }}
          />
          <ImageListItemBar
            title={item.title}
            subtitle={item.author}
            actionIcon={
              <IconButton
                sx={{ color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)' }}
                aria-label={`info about ${item.title}`}
              >
                <InfoIcon />
              </IconButton>
            }
          />
))
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. But I think I will go for extracting the component, I don't really want to turn the state into a object. Thanks for your ans tho!

Comment: You don't have to go straight to an array/object, a _number_ gives higher cardinality than a boolean (either representing the index of a single active item, or a bitmask for multiple active items 11 -> `1011`).

Comment: What do you mean by cardinality? The drawback I can think of is I cannot externally access or control the boolean state in a extracted component. But if I don't go to an array/object, how can I achieve the purpose of assigning each individual state in a map function?

Comment: @DavidHo I mean a boolean can only represent a single thing on or off (cardinality of 1), whereas a number can represent multiple things at once. I've posted an answer showing how this could work for either a single thing active at once or multiple things independently.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the state to be in the parent *without* going all the way to an array or object, you can use a number instead. If only one item at a time is going to be active, you can just use the index of the active item as the state:

```js
const { useState } = React;
const things = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

function Component() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(-1);
  const updateActivity = (index) => setActive(index === active ? -1 : index);
  return (
    <ul>
      {things.map((thing, index) => (
        <li>
          <button key={index} onClick={() => updateActivity(index)}>
            {index === active
              ? <strong>{thing}</strong>
              : thing}
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
      <li>Value: {active}</li>
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Alternatively, in cases where you want *multiple* items to be simultaneously active, you can use a "bit flag" approach where each bit of the value represents whether or not the corresponding index is active:

```js
const { useState } = React;
const things = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

function Component() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);
  const updateActivity = (index) => setActive(active ^ Math.pow(2, index));
  return (
    <ul>
      {things.map((thing, index) => (
        <li>
          <button key={index} onClick={() => updateActivity(index)}>
            {active & Math.pow(2, index)
              ? <strong>{thing}</strong>
              : thing}
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
      <li>Value: {active} ({active.toString(2).padStart(3, "0")})</li>
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("react2")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react2"></div>
```