# How to useState() when I click on an element that is part of an array of elements, only affecting that element

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
// Using a boolean data type as state
const [layerOne, setLayerOne] = useState(false)

// Looping three elements and I want to modify only the element that I click
{[1, 2, 3].map((o, i) => (
          <div
            key={i}
            id={`opt-${i}`}
            className="option"
            onClick={() => setLayerOne(!layerOne)}
          >
            {layerOne ? <BsEyeSlashFill size={21} /> : <BsEyeFill size={21} />}
            <div className="option__tittle">
              {layerOne ? 'hide' : 'show'} layer
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
```

In the code above I am trying to modify only the element where I click. In case I decided to use a specific boolean state for each item in the map().

How can I achieve this solution?

Comment: You _didn't_ use a specific boolean for each item in the map, you have a single one for all of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map components and ensure the component has the same attribute individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72430075/how-to-map-components-and-ensure-the-component-has-the-same-attribute-individual)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make each child element have it's own state, like this:

```
const SetLayer = () => {
  const [layerOne, setLayerOne] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div
      key={i}
      id={`opt-${i}`}
      className="option"
      onClick={() => setLayerOne(!layerOne)}
    >
      {layerOne ? <BsEyeSlashFill size={21} /> : <BsEyeFill size={21} />}
      <div className="option__tittle">
        {layerOne ? 'hide' : 'show'} layer
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    [1, 2, 3].map((o, i) => (
      <div
        key={i}
        id={`opt-${i}`}
      >
        <SetLayer />
      </div>
    ))
  )
}
```