# To make list of checkbox behave as radio button

Tags: reactjs

I have created a checkbox with the list of data in useState. Now I need to make the checkbox work as a radio button. what kind of logic I need to use to make a checkbox work as a radio button

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Checkbox = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
        { id: 1, checked: false, item: "apple" },
        { id: 2, checked: false, item: "bananna" },
        { id: 3, checked: false, item: "cherry" },
        { id: 4, checked: false, item: "dragon fruit" }
      ]);
      const handleCheck = (id) => {
        const listItem = items.map((item) => item.id === id ? {...item, checked: !item.checked} : item)
        setItems(listItem)
      }
        

    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
               {
                items.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.id}>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            checked = {item.checked}
                            onChange = {() =>handleCheck(item.id)}
                        />
                        <lable>{item.item}</lable>
                    </li>
                ))
               }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Checkbox;
```

Comment: Why not have a single state value representing the ID of the checked option, if any?

Comment: can u explain clearly I am new to programming

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/72449897/3001761

Answer (score 1):

Just set all the other items' `checked` properties to false:

```
const handleCheck = (id) => {
        const listItem = items.map((item) =>
          item.id === id
            ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked }
            : { ...item, checked: false }
        );
        setItems(listItem);
      };
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this as radio button logic, like selecting only one check box at a time.

while setting `true` for a particular checkbox, you can also set `false` for rest of the checkboxes

```
  const handleCheck = (id) => {
    const listItem = 
    items.map((item) => 
    item.id === id ? {...item, checked: !item.checked} : {...item, checked: false} )
    setItems(listItem)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit complicated since it's not a built-in functionality.
In order to make the checkboxes work as radio buttons, you can modify the handleCheck function to uncheck all the other items when one item is checked.

Here's one way to do that:

```
const handleCheck = (id) => {
  const listItem = items.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === id) {
      return {...item, checked: !item.checked};
    } else {
      return {...item, checked: false};
    }
  });
  setItems(listItem);
}
```

This will uncheck all the other items whenever one item is checked, so that only one item can be selected at a time, like a radio button.

Of course, there's also the built-in

```
<input
  type="radio"
  checked={item.checked}
  onChange={() => handleCheck(item.id)}
/>
```