# When using map in typescript, how to only get one element to be effected by click?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently trying to change a buttons icon when that button is selected, however because I am using map, all of the buttons are effected even when only one is selected

```
// ...

const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
<Button
  startIcon={
    clicked ? <RadioButtonUncheckedIcon /> : <RadioButtonCheckedIcon />
  }
  sx={{ textAlign: "left" }}
  key={key._id}
  className={`answer-button ${selectedAnswer === key.text ? "selected" : ""}`}
  onClick={() => {
    handleAnswerClick(key.text);
    setClicked(true);
  }}
>
  {key.text}
</Button>
```

I have attempted to set the use state in my handleAnswerClick function however this produces the same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map components and ensure the component has the same attribute individually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72430075/how-to-map-components-and-ensure-the-component-has-the-same-attribute-individual)

Comment: @jonrsharpe i dont think so because theyre not using useStates of type boolean - i cant set my useState to answer

Comment: @jonrsharpe my problem is i cant just set one of the buttons to true. it gets set true for all

Answer (score 0):

the issue here is that all the button set the `startIcon` property based on `clicked` so when you click any one, `clicked` is set to `true` so all the buttons have `<RadioButtonUncheckedIcon />` as `startIcon` you want to make `clicked` an array where each element there is for a specific button:

```js
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(Array(buttons.length).fill(false));
 //...
{buttons.map((key, index) => (
  <Button
    startIcon={
      clicked[index] ? <RadioButtonUncheckedIcon /> : <RadioButtonCheckedIcon />
    }
    key={key._id}
    onClick={() => {
      handleAnswerClick(key.text);
      setClicked(prev => {
        const newClicked = [...prev];
        newClicked[index] = true;
        return newClicked;
      });
    }}
  >
    {key.text}
  </Button>
))}
```