# changing active state of buttons in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-hooks

Please help I can't figure out how to do this in react
so I have three buttons and I need to make it so when you click on a button the state of others sets back to `false`.

Here's the code:

```
import votingimg from '../assets/header-assets/voting-img.png'
import galleryimg from '../assets/header-assets/gallery-img.png'
import breedsimg from '../assets/header-assets/breeds-img.png'
import { useState } from 'react'



import votingimg from '../assets/header-assets/voting-img.png'
import galleryimg from '../assets/header-assets/gallery-img.png'
import breedsimg from '../assets/header-assets/breeds-img.png'
import { useState } from 'react'

const Actions = () => {

  const [votingActive, setVotingActive] = useState(false)
  const [galleryActive, setGalleryActive] = useState(false)
  const [breedsActive, setBreedsActive] = useState(false)

  const votingOnClick = () => {
    setVotingActive(true)
    setGalleryActive(false)
    setBreedsActive(false)
  }

  const galleryOnClick = () => {
    setVotingActive(false)
    setGalleryActive(true)
    setBreedsActive(false)
  }

  const breedsOnClick = () => {
    setVotingActive(false)
    setVotingActive(false)
    setBreedsActive(true)
  }
  // im sorry about this code

  return (
    <div className='action__wrapper'>
      <div className="action">
        <div className='voting__bg'>
        <img className='action__img' src={votingimg} alt="voting" />
        </div>
        <button className={votingActive ? 'active__btn' : 'action__btn'}
        onClick={votingOnClick}
        >voting</button>
      </div>
      <div className="action">
        <div className="breeds__bg">
        <img className='action__img-breeds' src={breedsimg} alt="breeds" />
        </div>
        <button className={breedsActive ? 'active__btn' : 'action__btn'}
        onClick={breedsOnClick}>breeds</button>
      </div>
      <div className="action">
        <div className="gallery__bg">
        <img className='action__img-gallery' src={galleryimg} alt="gallery" />
        </div>
        <button className={galleryActive ? 'active__btn' : 'action__btn'}
        onClick={galleryOnClick}>gallery</button>
      </div>
      {/* each of this could be just a reusable component */}
      {/* need to change export to svg for netter quality */}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Actions
```

i know that my solution is bad but it works, all i found is solutions in vanilla js or with class component react

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72449897/3001761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, each of the actions can be a reusable component, setting that up already lays down some of the work to get towards a solution you'd like.

So can start by thinking what properties you want to abstract into props for a reusable component. You got an image so need a source, an alt text and maybe a class for the image. You got a button so you need some label and a callback to do something when the button is clicked. For the background as well you want another class. And then because state is important you can add a prop to represent whether or not the action is active. So if you were setting this up in typescript, you get a Props type like this

```
type ActionProps = {
  readonly src: string;
  readonly alt: string;
  readonly backgroundClassName: string;
  readonly imageClassName: string;
  readonly isActive: boolean;
  readonly onClick: () => void;
  readonly buttonLabel: string;
};
```

Then you can create your component

```
const Action = (props: ActionProps) => {
  const {
    buttonLabel,
    src,
    alt,
    isActive,
    imageClassName,
    backgroundClassName,
    onClick,
  } = props;
  return (
    <div className="action">
      <div className={backgroundClassName}>
        <img {...{ src, alt }} className={imageClassName} />
      </div>
      <button {...{ onClick }} className={isActive ? 'active' : ''}>
        {buttonLabel}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is basically what you had already but as a component.
Now you have a reusable component, and it takes a prop value to represent whether it's active or not, so you've lifted the stateful logic out of the component and its now the parent's responsibility to determine whether each action is active or not.

Then you can think about how to represent the state, you said one state for each action is not ideal, and its not. So now that you have a reusable component you could have a hundred actions. But you're only interested in tracking the state of one variable, active. So instead of approaching state from a per action basis, where each state tracks all stateful variables for an action, you can instead approach it from a per variable basis, where each state tracks one variable for all actions.

To do this you generally will need some property on each component you want to track that will help identify that variable, an `id` or `name`. So we can change `buttonLabel` prop to `name` and also use it for button for now.

So to track the state you can set up one state that expects to hold the name of an action.

```
const [activeAction,setActiveAction]=useState<string>('');
```

You can start with an empty string if you know no names are gonna be empty strings. Or allow `null` to be an accepted value for the state and start on that.

```
const [activeAction,setActiveAction]=useState<string|null>(null);
```

Then one more thing you got to do, now that each element will be rendered by a component, is set up the data so that it can be passed to component. Arrays work well for this, so let's assume you've made an array, `data`, containing elements that each have a name, a src, an image class name, etc... all the props to render a component.

Then in the parent component you can render the component for each data item by mapping through it and providing the props.

```
export default function App() {
  const [activeAction, setActiveAction] = useState<string | null>(null);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(({ alt, name, src }) => (
        <Action
          src={src}
          alt={alt}
          name={name}
          backgroundClassName=""
          imageClassName=""
          isActive={name === activeAction}
          onClick={() => setActiveAction(name)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Specifically, you pass the value for `isActive` as `true` if the action's `name` equals the current state that is tracking which item is active. And you provide `onClick` such that it sets the current active action to the name.

Here's a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vqhh25?file=src%2FApp.tsx) to an example.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you so much Max! you're my hero <3

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use only one `useState`? For example:

```
const [btnsState, setBtnsState] = useState({
  votingActive: false,
  galleryActive: false,
  breedsActive: false,
});
```

So you can define a function that will change all states to false and then set the state you want to true, something like that:

```
// the key parameter in the function is the key you want to change in the object to true
const changeState = (key) => {
  // copy the current state
  const stateCopy = structuredClone(btnsState);

  // loop through the object
  for (const prop in copy) {
    // change keys different from the one you want to be true to false
    if (prop !== key) {
      copy[prop] = false;
    }
  }
  //change the key you want to be true to true
  stateCopy[key] = true;

  // set the new state
  setBtnsState(stateCopy);
};
```

Of course there are other ways to do that, but this one is kinda simple and can be improved too.

Comment: dont really understand the structuredClone, sorry didnt work for me

Comment: structuredClone clones the state of useState assuring the original value will not be modified. As an alternative you can clone like so: const copy = {...btnsState}

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [buttonsState, setButtonsState] = useState({
    votingActive: false,
    galleryActive: false,
    breedsActive: false
  });

  const handleButtonState = (buttonName) => {
    setButtonsState({
      votingActive: buttonName === "voting",
      galleryActive: buttonName === "gallery",
      breedsActive: buttonName === "breeds"
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => handleButtonState("voting")}>Voting Button</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleButtonState("gallery")}>
        Gallery Button
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => handleButtonState("breeds")}>Breeds Button</button>

      // to check button state changes
      <p>Voting Active: {buttonsState.votingActive.toString()}</p>
      <p>Gallery Active: {buttonsState.galleryActive.toString()}</p>
      <p>Breeds Active: {buttonsState.breedsActive.toString()}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here, useState hook is used to manage the button states. Each button has an associated state (votingActive, galleryActive, breedsActive) that I'm maintaining in the buttonsState object.

For handling the button clicks, I've implemented the handleButtonState function. When a button is clicked, I call this function with the button's name.
Inside the function, I update the buttonsState using the setButtonsState function. I compare the clicked button's name with the button names and set the corresponding state to true and others to false.