# mouse event only for the current element react

Tags: reactjs

I want to display a `<TestComponent />` component on mouseover for the current element only, but on mouseover I get that component for all elements of the array.

```
const [Symbols, setSymbols] = useState([{ symbols: [] }]);
const [MouseComponent, setMouseComponent] = useState(false); <=== mouseover status state

{Symbols.map((field, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i}>
      {field.symbols.map((symbol, j) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={j}
            onMouseOver={() => setMouseComponent(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setMouseComponent(false)}          
          >
            {symbol}
            {MouseComponent ?
             <TestComponent />
            : null } 
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
})}
```

Also, I've tried doing a check for the current id, like this:

```
onMouseOver={() => {
   if (j)
   setButtonRemoveSymbol(true)
}}
```

But it also doesn't produce the desired behavior. I get `<TestComponent />` for all `symbol` except the first `symbol`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not my downvote, but what do you mean by 'current element' ? You probably need to save the index of the `map` you want to use onMouse events for

Comment: `if (j)` - what is that going to do?! Every index except `0` is truth-y. If you want these things to have _separate_ states, it's obviously a bad idea to have _one single boolean_ tracking that. (Not that you actually show _any_ symbols.) See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72430075/3001761.

Comment: @0stone0, I apologize for the poor explanation. I just want to get `<TestComponent />` for the element `symbol` on which `onMouseOver` occurred, but not for all `symbol`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to keep track of the index you want to show the hover component for

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [mouseIndex, setMouseIndex] = useState(-1);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            {[...Array(10)].map((e, i) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <div 
                        id={i} 
                        onMouseOver={() => setMouseIndex(i)}
                        onMouseLeave={() => setMouseIndex(-1)}    
                        >{'-->'}{i}
                    </div>
                    {(mouseIndex === i) && <TestElement />}
                </React.Fragment>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

const TestElement = () => {
  return (<div>FooBar</div>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: thanks you! Is there a possible solution using the values true and false for the state? instead of the index.

Comment: Yes but than you'll need to let the deeper component keep track of his own mouseOver state and not let your parent do it

Comment: Or you have an _array_ of booleans (or equivalently a bitflag as a number, as demonstrated on the linked question above). Your representation of the state has to at least match the cardinality you're actually trying to model.