# How to individualize a reused component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an iteration of cards with which each cards needs its own `MoreoptionPopup` component. Right now with the code I have implemented, once I click the more options icon *all* the More option Popups open up. And I get why they behave that way. But, I cannot figure out how to make each instance of `MoreoptionPopup` component a unique item that will only be opened from its own parent element.

I tried adding the key attribute to the `MoreoptionPopup` but still didn't work correctly.

See image attached for a visual representation of the behavior I would like to happen.

```
return (
    <div className="bucketlist_boards">
      <div className=" boards newBoard">
        <button className="board_openpopup" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop1" >+ Add New Board </button>
      </div>
      {getBoards.length > 0 ? (
        getBoards.map((item, id) => (
          <div key={id} className={`boards ${id}`}>
            <span className="more-options" onClick={(e) => handleMoreOptionsClick(e, item)} >
              <img src={Moreoption} alt="More options" />
            </span>
            <span className="board-name">{item.name}</span>

            { showPopup && (
              <MoreoptionPopup
                onClose={handleClosePopup}
                onEdit={() => {
                  setShowEditPopup(true); // Open the EditPopup
                  setCurrentImage(currentBoard?.image_url); // Set the current image URL
                }}
                onMakePublic={() => {
                  /* Implementation */
                }}
                onDelete={() => {
                  /* Implementation */
                }}
              />
            )}
            {showEditPopup && (
              <EditPopup onClose={handleClosePopup} imageSrc={currentImage} />
            )}
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <div className="bordercard">
          <div className="welcome-message">
            Welcome.
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: Without a [mre] it's hard to see what the problem is, but I'm guessing you need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72449897/3001761).