Trigger handle click on only one item at a time in a map
I am working on an app that allows the user to select a vehicle from a list.  The problem I am having at the moment is that when I try to map the vehicles to a list and select a single vehicle to set a class to,  all of the other items in that list are also being set with the same class. Following is the code structure I am having issues with:
The expected outcome of this code is to be able to set a single border around a clicked item in a mapped set of objects. I have attempted a couple different ways of setting this, including trying to exclude all other non-clicked id's, setting to the name of the item instead of the ID, and using false/true to set the state instead of the ID.
Dummy data to populate the map:
  const tempMapObjects = [
        { id: 0, name: 'placeholder 1', vehicle: Vehicle1, alt: 'vehicle 1' },
        { id: 1, name: 'placeholder 2', vehicle: Vehicle2, alt: 'vehicle 2' },
    ];

Setting the initial state:
const [selectedIdClass, setSelectedIdClass] = useState(0);

Handler:
  const handleClickedVehicle = (id) => {
        console.log("reached handle Click")
        setSelectedIdClass(!id)
    }

Map:
 {tempMapObjects.map((obj) => {                                 return (                                     <div                                         className={selectedIdClass ? style['Card2'] : style['Card']}                                         key={obj.id}>                                         <a className={style['ALink']}                                             onClick={(e) => (                                                 handleClickedVehicle({                                                     id: obj.id                                                 })                                             <img className={style['ImgDimensions']} src={obj.vehicle} alt={obj.alt} />                                             <h6 className={style['StyleVehicleBox']}> {obj.name} </h6>                                         </a>                                     </div>                                 )                             })}   

How can I set only the state of the currently clicked item in the map list, and not highlight the others?

setSelectedIdClass(!id) - what? That just toggles between true and false, a single piece of state; you need something more (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72449897/3001761) to handle separate states. The other things you vaguely describe seem more sensible, maybe give a [mre] of that if it doesn't work.

You need to make sure that selectedIdClass state holds the ID of the currently selected item and compare this ID with each item's ID when rendering to decide which class to apply.
First, in the handleClickedVehicle function, you need to path the id to the setSelectedIdClass state.
const handleClickedVehicle = (id) => {
    setSelectedIdClass(id);
}

Then conditionally check in the loop, if the current item id is equal to selectedIdClass.
{tempMapObjects.map((obj) => {
    return (
        <div
            className={selectedIdClass === obj.id ? style['Card2'] : style['Card']}
            key={obj.id}>
            <a className={style['ALink']}
               onClick={() => handleClickedVehicle(obj.id)}>
                <img className={style['ImgDimensions']} src={obj.vehicle} alt={obj.alt} />
                <h6 className={style['StyleVehicleBox']}>{obj.name}</h6>
            </a>
        </div>
    )
})}

Also, I suggest renaming selectedIdClass to selectedItemId ( optionally )
